# Intersperse values into separate Vectors using generate

Tags: haskell, repa, haskell-vector

I am trying to generate a tuple of `Vector`s by using a function that creates a custom data type (or a tuple) of values from an index. Here is an approach that achieves the desired result:

```
import Prelude hiding (map, unzip)
import Data.Vector hiding (map)
import Data.Array.Repa
import Data.Functor.Identity

data Foo = Foo {fooX :: Int, fooY :: Int}

unfoo :: Foo -> (Int, Int)
unfoo (Foo x y) = (x, y)

make :: Int -> (Int -> Foo) -> (Vector Int, Vector Int)
make n f = unzip $ generate n getElt where
  getElt i = unfoo $ f i
```

Except that I would like to do it in a single iteration per Vector, almost like it is shown below, but avoiding multiple evaluation of function `f`:

```
make' :: Int -> (Int -> Foo) -> (Vector Int, Vector Int)
make' n f = (generate n getElt1, generate n getElt2) where
  getElt1 i = fooX $ f i
  getElt2 i = fooY $ f i
```

Just as a note, I understand that `Vector` library supports fusion, and the first example is already pretty efficient. I need a solution to `generate` concept, other libraries have very similar constructors (Repa has `fromFunction` for example), and I am using `Vector`s here simply to demonstrate a problem.

Maybe some sort of memoizing of `f` function call would work, but I cannot think of anything.

**Edit:**

Another demonstration of the problem using Repa:

```
makeR :: Int -> (Int -> Foo) -> (Array U DIM1 Int, Array U DIM1 Int)
makeR n f = runIdentity $ do
  let arr = fromFunction (Z :. n) (\ (Z :. i) -> unfoo $ f i)
  arr1 <- computeP $ map fst arr
  arr2 <- computeP $ map snd arr
  return (arr1, arr2)
```

<strike>Same as with vectors, fusion saves the day on performance</strike>, but an intermediate array `arr` of tuples is still required, which I am trying to avoid.

**Edit 2: (3 years later)**

In the Repa example above it will not create an intermediate array, since `fromFunction` creates a delayed array. Instead it will be even worse, it will evaluate `f` twice for each index, one for the first array, second time for the second array. Delayed array must be computed in order to avoid such duplication of work.

Comment: It definitely won't be more efficient than your first version, but if you want to memorize all the `Foo`s you can do `generateM` and carry an `IntMap Foo` around in `State` monad, then use the `IntMap` to generate the second vector.

Comment: That would work with a `Vector` but unfortunately I cannot use a monad in this particular situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back at my own question from a few years ago I can now easily show what I was trying to do back than and how to get it done.

In short, it can't be done purely, therefore we need to resort to `ST` monad and manual mutation of two vectors, but in the end we do get this nice and pure function that creates only two vectors and does not rely on fusion.

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Vector.Primitive
import Data.Vector.Primitive.Mutable

data Foo = Foo {fooX :: Int, fooY :: Int}

make :: Int -> (Int -> Foo) -> (Vector Int, Vector Int)
make n f = runST $ do
  let n' = max 0 n
  mv1 <- new n'
  mv2 <- new n'
  let fillVectors i
        | i < n' = let Foo x y = f i
                   in write mv1 i x >> write mv2 i y >> fillVectors (i + 1)
        | otherwise = return ()
  fillVectors 0
  v1 <- unsafeFreeze mv1
  v2 <- unsafeFreeze mv2
  return (v1, v2)
```

And the we use it in a similar fashion it is done with `generate`:

```
λ> make 10 (\ i -> Foo (i + i) (i * i))
([0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18],[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81])
```

Answer (score 0):

The essential thing you're trying to write is

```
splat f = unzip . fmap f
```

which shares the results of evaluating `f` between the two result vectors, but you want to avoid the intermediate vector. Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure you can't have it both ways in any meaningful sense. Consider a vector of length 1 for simplicity. In order for the result vectors to share the result of `f (v ! 0)`, each will need a reference to a thunk representing that result. Well, that thunk has to *be* somewhere, and it really might as well be in a vector.

Comment: I am pretty sure I cannot have it both ways too, but I wanted some reassurance from the community. Thank you for the answer though.